# how do you create an <h1> tag programmatically in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to generate some html programmatically in my code behind for a user control I'm designing.

I've been looking around, but can't seem to figure out how to dynamically generate some h1 tags for content I'll be displaying.

Is it just a Label with a special property set?

Comment: Are you in a DataBound controls ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
var h1 = new HtmlGenericControl("h1");
h1.InnerHtml = "header content";
```

Comment: @umair.ali you can add it to any `Controls` collection and the server will render it correctly.

Answer (score 11):

You could also use:

```
<h1 runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use label or literal controls as shown below:

```
Label1.Text = "<h1>HI All</h1>";
```

Or

```
string heading = "HI All";
Label1.Text = string.Format("<h1>{0}</h1>", heading);
```

Comment: of course, it can be as simple as that .. why did i forgot to do that .. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily by

```
literall.Text ="<h1>ABCD</h1>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Let, you have a server control like this,

```
<div class="cls" runat="server" id="MyServerControlDiv"></div>
```

using `HtmlGenericControl`

```
var h1 = new HtmlGenericControl("h1");
h1.InnerHtml = "header content";
MyServerControlDiv.Controls.Add(h1);
```

using `LiteralControl`

```
MyServerControlDiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<h1>"));
MyServerControlDiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("header content"));
MyServerControlDiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</h1>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Literal control, `Literal1.Text = "<h1>" + texttodisplay + "</h1>";`

Answer (score 1):

ASP literals may help you.

http://ganeshmohan.wordpress.com/aspnet-and-c-generate-html-controls-dynamically/

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer to make a class for it.

```
public class H1: HtmlGenericElement 
{
    public H1(): base("h1") { }
}
```

Or maybe.

```
public class H: HtmlGenericControl
{
    public H(int size): base("h" + size) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that you have an asp placeholder in your design:

```
PlaceHolder placeHolder1 = new PlaceHolder();

string yourText = "Header Text";
Label myLabel = new Label();
myLabel.Text = "<h1>" + yourText + "</h1>";

PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myLabel);
```

OR

```
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl ("<h1>")) // and likewise
for </h1>.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a generic HTML control or a literal control is fine just so long as you don't want to insert any child controls.  If you do need to append a child control such as a label for example, then you will want to create you header as a Web Control like follows:

```
WebControl H2Header = new WebControl(HtmlTextWriterTag.H1);
```

And then you can append a child control like this:

```
Label labHeader = new Label() { Text = "Some Header Text" };
H2Header.Controls.Add(labHeader);
```

Answer (score 0):

What i always prefer to use:

In the front end put the desired html control like

```
<h1 id="title" runat="server">XXX</h1>
```

Then in the behind code declare the desired control like

```
protected HtmlGenericControl PublicTitle
{
   get
   {
       return this.title;
   }
}
```

And anywhere in the code play whith the control

```
PublicTitle.InnerHtml = state.Equals("win") ? "Win" : "Lost";
PublicTitle.Attributes.Add("src", "https://xxxx");
```